# Mixture of two gamma distributions, finding MLE

Tags: probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

I want to find the MLE of $ \pi_0, \beta_1, \beta_2 $ from the following:

$$
X_i \sim \pi_0\Gamma(1, β_1) + π_1\Gamma(1, β_2)
$$

So far I have got

$$
f(X_i) = \pi_0 \exp (-\sum_i x_i / \beta_1) /\beta_1 + \pi_1 \exp (-\sum_i x_i / \beta_2) /\beta_2
$$

Comment: please format ur question properly

Comment: What is $f(.)$ meant to be?